# R: Interpreting distance classes in correlog {pgirmess}?

Tags: r, distance, spatial

I'm using the `correlog` function in the `pgirmess` package to get Moran's I over 20-30 distance classes, but am not sure what the unit of measurement is for the output distance classes. The input coordinates are in decimal degrees. The function documentation notes "Distances are euclidian and in the same unit as the spatial coordinates", but I'm still not exactly sure how to interpret the distance classes in the output - are the distance class bins in m, km, degrees, etc? Here's my code:

```
# longitude = mid.lon
# latitude = mid.lat
# variable of interest for spatial autocorrelation = std_cpue

library(pgirmess)
library(spdep)
df.xy = cbind(data$mid.lon, data$mid.lat)
pgi.cor = correlog(coords=df.xy, z=data$std_cpue, method="Moran", nbclass=30)
```

With 30 neighborhood classes, the result for the entire dataset looks like this. The distance class given is the midpoint for the bin:

```
 print(pgi.cor)
    # Moran I statistic 
    #     dist.class          coef      p.value       n
    # [1,]  0.2519862  2.738572e-02 3.911359e-32  698490
    # [2,]  0.7559590 -2.650938e-03 9.050678e-01 1084054
    # [3,]  1.2599313  6.667723e-05 4.116504e-01 1063526
    # [4,]  1.7639037  3.513692e-03 1.228453e-02  884720
    # [5,]  2.2678760  2.719341e-03 4.536515e-02  729678
    # [6,]  2.7718483 -5.959940e-03 9.988661e-01  690428
    # [7,]  3.2758207  3.388526e-03 2.280808e-02  718940
    # [8,]  3.7797930  1.443793e-03 1.830925e-01  633504
    # [9,]  4.2837653 -4.573091e-04 5.278008e-01  519468
    # [10,]  4.7877377 -8.749218e-03 9.999291e-01  397686
    # [11,]  5.2917100  2.405016e-03 1.493334e-01  311976
    # [12,]  5.7956823  2.089573e-03 2.258621e-01  256072
    # [13,]  6.2996547 -1.182670e-03 5.998478e-01  202578
    # [14,]  6.8036270 -2.270657e-03 7.158043e-01  166596
    # [15,]  7.3075993 -4.629743e-03 9.011101e-01  156026
    # [16,]  7.8115716 -3.213096e-03 8.094323e-01  160848
    # [17,]  8.3155440 -4.373410e-03 8.707319e-01  163870
    # [18,]  8.8195163 -3.356690e-04 5.015126e-01  169376
    # [19,]  9.3234886 -4.467592e-03 8.685484e-01  169512
    # [20,]  9.8274610 -2.546946e-03 7.127175e-01  150146
    # [21,] 10.3314333  1.370106e-02 4.662235e-04  122808
    # [22,] 10.8354056 -8.699153e-03 9.719764e-01  109024
    # [23,] 11.3393780 -9.322568e-03 9.750500e-01  102748
    # [24,] 11.8433503 -2.383252e-03 6.464213e-01   85680
    # [25,] 12.3473226 -3.473310e-03 7.210551e-01   85942
    # [26,] 12.8512950  2.053248e-03 3.396486e-01   66042
    # [27,] 13.3552673 -1.037403e-02 8.547700e-01   32428
    # [28,] 13.8592396 -1.033826e-02 6.762256e-01   11012
    # [29,] 14.3632120 -3.007297e-02 7.217509e-01    1244
    # [30,] 14.8671843 -6.886551e-02 6.864535e-01     154
```

Reproducible data (only the first 50 rows of the dataset):

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(mid.lat = c(28.7969496928494, 28.3930867867479, 
29.994, 27.4784336939524, 29.422593551961, 28.5826238813314, 
28.7477216329144, 29.3433487514478, 29.4226940782315, 29.3535708114362, 
28.113333, 28.1130776659231, 28.2415339610655, 29.0009495727289, 
29.7557386166675, 30.1020183777123, 28.0200002127096, 28.7864004408834, 
30.1284937679637, 29.8328992823496, 28.9037836662043, 29.8021310079424, 
28.0232807300034, 28.3553360292622, 29.0875191742967, 29.0220856353549, 
27.9313060847168, 28.83, 29.5104509959267, 29.8466720353246, 
28.8814346610816, 28.1373531188643, 29.3582385823534, 28.809044113648, 
29.3867773013913, 29.4805574724306, 28.465504194069, 28.6696044277849, 
29.5300092012194, 28.0430185205882, 28.2061620529272, 29.4275806851126, 
26.5081134049796, 28.1275544648238, 29.8995981792495, 27.9848607011733, 
26.709333, 28.0248252141179, 27.9728617106042, 28.9710761741436
), mid.lon = c(-84.5963462803782, -90.2686343226641, -87.374667, 
-84.7457473224263, -87.9880238574933, -84.8349303764527, -84.6637647705975, 
-87.8703015583197, -87.6622139897327, -88.5050810721282, -94.3925, 
-90.346370340355, -92.8455008541893, -85.8699396759243, -86.9236199327813, 
-86.9270244367842, -84.1683543397277, -89.2031178427517, -86.7908469980617, 
-86.7643717886603, -85.819506226643, -86.7113004426214, -95.8135406472186, 
-91.6316607122335, -85.2654292446955, -85.3228098920376, -93.9566215033579, 
-89.526667, -87.6660902037082, -86.0710278956076, -89.5803704536036, 
-90.8071728375477, -85.9890923714648, -84.7585523170688, -86.3493169018374, 
-87.9960861956136, -84.266238497227, -84.5619763017653, -87.516209287989, 
-91.3888746998191, -90.5451786588464, -87.3552938848394, -82.8477832707687, 
-93.3828028011249, -86.2444455292202, -95.0747515699181, -82.891333, 
-93.7656918819001, -92.8027598646245, -85.9850645824538), std_cpue = c(4.15234074914, 
5.66057254934, 9.18436048054, 57.3175320669, 18.8400703246, 1843.47803667, 
2.11506377428, 12.7170026758, 11.1626934066, 8.54011518736, 15.86758562, 
13.8956556998, 4.38083061994, 67.7079534217, 5.76247720007, 25.4144340451, 
9.46034915015, 14.8236026456, 22.8203364264, 5.79376884735, 89.6224743353, 
8.45411201327, 23.9702041714, 13.1097292376, 75.4677852659, 1.56569331032, 
44.990410447, 19.7090607295, 18.1197937416, 21.593493236, 46.9911787332, 
19.2194902326, 55.782614307, 12.6585921867, 87.6939183102, 7.76649659183, 
5.01359412606, 14.7829900356, 28.2493550901, 22.752832268, 7.43168604362, 
75.9057643933, 1.18254364377, 5.98151873107, 23.1061861061, 41.3675267384, 
11.4449526399, 45.7536886171, 10.6669337284, 66.5718319458)), .Names = c("mid.lat", 
"mid.lon", "std_cpue"), row.names = c(1L, 67L, 69L, 536L, 842L, 
2203L, 2586L, 2997L, 2998L, 3472L, 3474L, 3475L, 3855L, 4582L, 
5084L, 5088L, 5987L, 6776L, 6778L, 7648L, 7651L, 8075L, 8079L, 
8086L, 9069L, 9073L, 9080L, 9532L, 10526L, 11307L, 11308L, 11683L, 
12082L, 12086L, 12087L, 12094L, 12500L, 12503L, 12505L, 12506L, 
12507L, 12994L, 13016L, 13488L, 13497L, 13507L, 13520L, 14605L, 
15487L, 15792L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "how to interpret the distance classes in the output"?

Comment: My memory and search skills don't serve me right now, but something similar was asked some time ago on r-sig-geo?

Comment: Sure @BPS - I mean what are the distance units - degrees, meters, km? I edited the question above to clarify as well.

Answer (score 0):

After working with this data and the `spdep` package a bit more, I believe that the distance class variable here is in km. Other functions that take decimal degree coordinates as inputs also give outputs in km, or Great Circle distances (which are in km). Since the `correlog` documentation notes that "Distances are euclidian and in the same unit as the spatial coordinates", I'm interpreting this as km. An example in "Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R" by Bivand et al. also indicated that the bins used in `coorelog` are in km.

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the function `correlog` it simply calculates the Euclidean distance of the coordinates you provided the function and returns the average distance for each `nbclass` bin you generate. Meaning it returns the `dist.class` values in the same units as you provided it.

It makes no special conversion from whatever format you provide it, the code snip below, you can see it calculate simple distances for the bins with no unit transformation.

```
function (coords, z, method = "Moran", nbclass = NULL, ...) 
{
  coords <- as.matrix(coords)
  matdist <- dist(coords)
...
  etendue <- range(matdist)
  breaks1 <- seq(etendue[1], etendue[2], l = nbclass + 1)
  breaks2 <- breaks1 + 0.000001
  breaks <- cbind(breaks1[1:length(breaks1) - 1], breaks2[2:length(breaks2)])
...
  res <- cbind(dist.class = rowMeans(breaks), coef = mat[, 
    1], p.value = mat[, 2], n = mat[, 3])
}
```